# How can I encode a string using IBM-1047 charset?

Tags: java, encoding

I want to encode a string in IBM1047, but I just get an error message UnsupportedEncodingException. I am using jdk version 1.7.0_76.

```
 String sta ="abc";
 byte[] bytearray = sta.getBytes("IBM1047");
```

Comment: Please run the code from this webpage [Supported-Character-Encodings-in-JDK](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Java-charset-Supported-Character-Encodings-in-JDK.html)to see which code page is supported by your JDK. Would be surprised if `IBM1047` is not supported. `byte[] ebcdta="abc".getBytes("IBM1047");` works fine with version `1.7.0_40`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the supported locales for JDK 7:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

IBM1047 is supported, but according to the table *"Canonical Name for `java.io` API and `java.lang` API"* is Cp1047. So, this is what you want:

```
String sta ="abc";
byte[] bytearray = sta.getBytes("Cp1047");
```